# VB sleep command happening all at once in the begging of script

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub Main()
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
crt.Sleep(1000)
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send "6"
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send "1"
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send "y"
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
 crt.Screen.Send "1"
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
crt.Sleep(5000)
 crt.Screen.Send chr(13)
End Sub
```

Here is the code I'm working with now. just getting my feet wet with VB so the code is real simple. With the program I'm working in the "chr(13)" refers to the enter key. The problem I am having is the 5 sec sleep and the 1 sec sleep are happening before any of the key strokes. Am I missing something about the sleep function?

Comment: Almost impossible to diagnose with the code you've shown here, since `Main` is usually the entry point for a program but here you immediately start using `crt` without initializing it. Since we don't know what the data type of `crt` is, and since *every single line you've shown us* relies upon it, how do you expect us to diagnose the issue?

Comment: It's been a while since I have seen any, but that looks VBScript. Are you trying to write a VB.NET program or a VBScript program?